# Play framework 2.0 unresolved dependencies

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have created a scala project with play framework 2.0.
The project compiles and runs fine both with `sbt` and `play` commands.

However, the problems started when I tried to add another play project as a dependency to my project, because I needed to reuse some of its classes. 
`sbt compile` succeeds, but `play compile/run` does not. 
They give me the following error:

> `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: name_of_old_project_play_dependency: not found`

I am also not able to run the project with `sbt run`; whenever I do a request to the play framework, I get a null pointer exception.

Is that because both the projects are play projects and maybe there is a conflict somewhere?
Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: how did you add the old project as a dependency ? can you provide the build definition ?

Comment: Actually I solved it, the play-project I wanted to include as a dependency had some submodules which I had published in the local repository only through sbt. Then I also ran 'play publish-local' in the project I wanted to include in my own project, and everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure to view the play version since sbt (the build system play uses) may have different versions.

Please verify the build.properties and plugins.sbt play version.

A technique I use to solve unresolved dependencies is to check the links that sbt tries to access.
I manually try to fetch the file by visiting the failed sites. I usually discover I have a version mishap.